# Cannot understand how the GROUPING_ID() function is working in my case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query :

```
SELECT GROUPING_ID( shipcountry, shipregion, shipcity ) AS grp_id,
shipcountry, shipregion, shipcity,
COUNT(*) AS numorders
FROM Sales.Orders
GROUP BY ROLLUP( shipcountry, shipregion, shipcity );
```

This query generates the following output (shown here in abbreviated form):
grp_id shipcountry shipregion shipcity     numorders

```
0     Argentina   NULL       Buenos Aires 16
1     Argentina   NULL       NULL         16
3     Argentina   NULL       NULL         16
...
0     USA         AK         Anchorage    10
1     USA         AK         NULL         10
0     USA         CA         San Francisco 4
1     USA         CA         NULL          4
0     USA         ID         Boise        31
1     USA         ID         NULL         31
...
3     USA         NULL       NULL        122
...
7     NULL        NULL       NULL        830
```

I want to understand the logic behind the grp_id column and how the 0,1,3,7 are generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GROUPING_ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns an int with bits set specifying whether the corresponding column is aggregated or not (with "1" meaning aggregated).  So:

```
0   --> 000 --> no rollup
1   --> 001 --> rollup on shipcountry
7   --> 111 --> rollup on all three columns
```

And so on.  This function and `GROUPING()` are particularly useful when the key values can take on `NULL` values.  Often, `NULL` is used to determine what columns are being rolled up.  But that is not safe if the key itself can be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUPING_ID() accepts a list of some grouped columns as inouts and returns an integer representing a bitmap.
The rightmost bit represents the rightmost input.
The bit is 0 when the respective element
is part of the grouping set and 1 when it isn’t.
Each bit represents 2 raised to the power
of the bit position minus 1; so, the rightmost bit represents 1, the one to the left of it 2, then
4, then 8, and so on. The result integer is the sum of the values representing elements that are
not part of the grouping set because their bits are turned on.

Try to modify your query as below to understand the logic of the bits :

```
SELECT CAST(GROUPING(shipcountry) AS VARCHAR(1)) +
CAST(GROUPING(shipregion) AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(GROUPING(shipcity ) AS VARCHAR(1)) AS grp_id,
shipcountry, shipregion, shipcity,
COUNT(*) AS numorders
FROM Sales.Orders
GROUP BY ROLLUP( shipcountry, shipregion, shipcity );
```